# how to design REST API to ask server to wait for resource version to arrive on GET requests?

Tags: api, rest, cqrs

I work on splitting monoliths into microservices. With the monolith, I had a single source of truth and can just `GET /resources/123` right after the `PATCH /resources/123` and be sure that the database has the up-to-date data I need.

With microservices and CQRS in place, there is a risk that the query service has not seen yet the latest update to the record when I perform a GET request.

What is the best or standard approach to making sure that the client receives back the up-to-date value? I know that the client may compare resource versions that he receives after `PATCH` and after `GET` and retry requests, but is there a known API design to tell the server something like `GET /resources/123 and wait up to 5 sec for the resource version 45 or bigger to arrive`?

Answer (score 1):

Since a `PATCH` request allows a response body, to my mind there's nothing wrong with the response including the object after patching.  The requestor who sent the `PATCH` can use the response in lieu of a `GET`; for others, the eventual consistency delay for the `GET` isn't observable (since they don't know when the `PATCH` was issued).

CQRS means to not contort your write model for the sake of reads.  If there's a read that is easily performed based on the write model, that read can be done against the write model.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a better design might be for the `PATCH` request to delay its own response, if that's an option.

However, your `GET` request can also just 'hang' until it's ready. This generally feels like a better design than polling.

A client could indicate to the server how long it's willing to wait using a `Prefer: wait=` header: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7240#section-4.3

This could be used both for the `GET` or the `PATCH` request.

I don't think there's a standard HTTP way to say: this resource is not available right now, but will be in the future. However, there is a standard HTTP header to tell clients when to retry the request:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After

This is mainly used for 429 and 503 errors but neither seem appropriate here.

Frankly this is one of the first thing I've heard in a while that could be a good new HTTP status code. [425 Too Early](https://evertpot.com/http/425-too-early) exists but its a different use-case.